# Square brackets in php preg_match

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I would like to in form I can enter only the letters of the alphabet, numbers, and square brackets, except for special characters. Whether the brackets to include special characters? I have such:

```
if (preg_match("/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/", $characters))
{
    echo "Write only letters of alphabet and numbers!";
}
```

It detects letters and numbers correctly, does not pass the special characters but how to do that I can also enter the square brackets?

Comment: Just add them to the regex I suppose, escaped of course.

Comment: You don't need `+` in the regex. One match is enough to fail validation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As adeneo says,

```
if (preg_match('/[^a-zA-Z0-9\[\]]+/', $characters))
{
    echo "Letters, numbers and square brackets only!";
}
```

Comment: It should be `\\[\\]` or use single quotes